# I want to increase the div's width at every click

Tags: javascript, dom

I have two buttons one is to increase the width of div element and the other is to decrease the width of the div so how do I do that.

```js
let btn1 = document.querySelector("#increase");
btn1.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  let add = 100;
  let div = document.querySelector("div");
  // I am trying to add width to div every time I click
  let c = div.style.width = `300px`;
  c = c++;
})

let btn2 = document.querySelector("#decrease");
btn1.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  let add = 100;
  let div = document.querySelector("div");
  // I am trying to decrease width to div every time I click
  let c = div.style.width = `300px`;
  c = c--;
})
```

```html
<button id="b">big</button>
<button id="s">small</butto>
<div></div>
```

Comment: ` let c =  div.style.width=`300px`;` not sure what you think that is doing. Read the width, change it to a number, set the new width.

Answer (score 0):

on each button click call a javascript function. I that function you change the div width. An example from a similar function I use by passing the ID of the control into the function parm. Below shows the control expanding and retracting on each call:

```
    function collapseExpandMe(obj) {
        var x = document.getElementById(obj);

        if (x.style.width== "150px") {
            x.style.width= "500px";

        }
        else {
            x.style.width= "150px"
        }




    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with comments explaining how it was done;

```js
// redeclared these as const because they wont change
const btn1 = document.querySelector("#increase");
const btn2 = document.querySelector("#decrease");
// here is a variable to indicate how much to increase or decrease the divs width
const increment = 100;
// here I am storing a reference to the div so i don't have to constantly look it up
const targetDiv = document.getElementById('sample')

// The increase handler
btn1.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  // calculate the current width
  let currentWidth = window.getComputedStyle(targetDiv).width;
  // styles need the trailing 'px' and they come back with it, so we can drop the px by using parseInt
  // we add the 'px' back in the template 
  targetDiv.style.width = `${parseInt(currentWidth, 10) + increment}px`;
  // no need for the c variable
})

btn2.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  // calculate the current width
  let currentWidth = window.getComputedStyle(targetDiv).width;
  // styles need the trailing 'px' and they come back with it, so we can drop the px by using parseInt
  // we add the 'px' back in the template 
  targetDiv.style.width = `${parseInt(currentWidth, 10) - increment}px`;
  // no need for the c variable
})
```

```css
#sample {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!-- Your button id's didn't match what you were looking up so I updated them here -->
<button id="increase">increase</button>
<button id="decrease">decrease</button>
<!-- I added this just for some simple formatting -->
<br />
<!-- I gave the element an ID to be able to specifically target it -->
<!-- I also added a style and some content so you can see the div -->
<div id="sample">
Content
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you awesome.

Comment: @AhmedAli - Don't forget to upvote and mark it as the accepted answer if this helped you. It helps me reach more people.

Answer (score 0):

IF you have this:

```
<button id="increase">big</button>
<button id="decrease">small</button>
<div id="this-div"></div>
```

Then you could attach event listeners to those 2 buttons. You'll also need to read the current width of div element to be able to calculate new width.

So you need to start with fetching all elements from page that you will use:

```
const divElement =  document.querySelector("#this-div");
const btn1 = document.querySelector("#increase");
const btn2 = document.querySelector("#decrease");
```

After that, you need to attach event listeners.

```
btn1.addEventListener("click", () => {
   divElement.style.width = divElement.offsetWidth + 10 + "px"
});
btn2.addEventListener("click", () => {
  divElement.style.width = divElement.offsetWidth - 10 + "px"
});
```

Full example in codepen: https://codepen.io/gmaslic/pen/GRRKyag?editors=1111

Answer (score 0):

Copy this following code on your page and see what happened. Its working perfectly.

```
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>


   <button id="increase">big</button>
   <button id="decrease">small</button>
   <div id="my_div" style="width: 20px;height: 100px; background-color: red"></div>
   <script>

      let incresingValue = 20;

      function incresingDiv() {
         incresingValue += 10;
         document.getElementById("my_div").style.height = 100;
         document.getElementById("my_div").style.width = incresingValue;    
      }

      function decresingDiv() {
         incresingValue -= 10;
         document.getElementById("my_div").style.height = 100;
         document.getElementById("my_div").style.width = incresingValue;   
      }

      document.getElementById("increase").addEventListener('click', incresingDiv);
      document.getElementById("decrease").addEventListener('click', decresingDiv);


   </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: if this answer you are looking for be kind to press the upvote button in this answer sided.